# Filter an array containing dates

Tags: arrays, date, datetime, google-sheets, filter

[image: expected result]

Hi,
I'm trying to do the following in google sheet:

I have a table with dates and expenses (A2:E7) and I would be able to filter them by changing the values in cell H1 and H2. This would in turn generate as result a new table ranging from J2 to N?. My plan is to continue populating the A2:E7 table so it will grow in time but to still be able to look at my datas between two dates.

How can this be done?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=FILTER(A2:E; A2:A>=H1; A2:A<H2)
```